# Rails: Root Path Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I want to redirect to root path of my rails application to a controller that exists inside of a particular namespace. Is this possible?

Code:

```
    root to: 'production/static_pages#index'
```

I would like the root path to redirect to static_pages controller inside of my production namespace.

I have tried:

```
    namespace :production do
      root to: 'production/static_pages#index'
    end
```

But that only directions the root path in the production namespace to that appropriate controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my code works.

```
root to: 'production/static_pages#index'
```

is exactly how to connect the root path to a static_pages controller inside production namespace. 
Sorry for the confusion! o.o